# Get edge/outer coordinates of CGPoints

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cgpoint

I have a feature that user can draw/color a specific area of an image then get the drawn area as a cropping result.

[image]

Currently I store the draw coordinates inside an array, and in the end of the process I use **UIBezierPath** and **CGContextClipToMask** to crop the image. The problem is I only need the  outer coordinates from the draw coordinates I stored in array. Is there any way to filter CGPoints to only get the outer coordinates?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // add the first coordinate
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:lastPoint]];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   // add more coordinates as finger moves
   [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currentPoint]];

}

- (void) crop {


    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = self.mainImage.image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0);

     {

        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(rect);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

        UIBezierPath * beziPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        NSValue * firstValue = [points objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint firstPoint = firstValue.CGPointValue;
       [beziPath moveToPoint:[ARCroppingViewController
                       convertCGPoint:firstPoint fromRect1:self.mainImage.frame.size
                       toRect2:self.mainImage.image.size]];

        for (uint i = 1; i < points.count; i++) {


           NSValue * value = [points objectAtIndex:i];
           CGPoint point = value.CGPointValue;
           NSLog(@"point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
           [beziPath addLineToPoint:[ARCroppingViewController
                            convertCGPoint:point fromRect1:self.mainImage.frame.size
                            toRect2:self.mainImage.image.size]];

           }

     [beziPath closePath];
     [beziPath fill];


      }


     UIImage *mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
    {

      CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, mask.CGImage);
      [self.mainImage.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    }

     UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     NSLog(@"mask image: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(maskedImage.size));
     self.mainImage.image = maskedImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the edge, I would save the extreme values already in the saving phase (adding points to array). So holding the highest and lowest x and y value. think its also easier than filtering the array :)

*edit*

```
int xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
-(void)resetValues
{
    xMax = yMax = 0;

    xMin = yMin = self.mainImage.image.size.width;
}

- (void)checkForExtremes:(CGPoint)point
{
    // Have my IDE not here for checking the MIN() and MAX(), so using this way :P
    lastPoint.x > xMax ? xMax = lastPoint.x : nil;
    lastPoint.x < xMin ? xMin = lastPoint.x : nil;
    lastPoint.y > yMax ? yMax = lastPoint.y : nil;
    lastPoint.y < yMin ? yMin = lastPoint.y : nil;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // add the first coordinate
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:lastPoint]];

    [self checkForExtremes:lastPoint];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   // add more coordinates as finger moves
   [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currentPoint]];
   [self checkForExtremes:currentPoint];
}
```

btw, the result is then

[image: cut Image]

Comment: How to get the extreme values?

Comment: thanks, gonna try your answer. But I need an exact circle crop result (as the same as the drawing path)

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the points (as you are now) but check each point and store the max and min for the x and y values. Then at the end of the loop you can get the 4 points at the corners of the (now square) selected region.

```
CGFloat minX, maxX, minY, maxY;

for (... {
    minX = MIN(minX, point.x);
    maxX = ...
}

CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(minX, minY);
CGPoint topRight = ...
```

You could also perform these calculations while the user is tracing the shape (you could also modify the bezier path then too).